# How to get value if detailview yii with csqldataprovider

Tags: yii

I have trouble in cdetail view yii, why does the value show "not set" in detailview,  i used `csqldataprovider` for source data, this is mycode:

```
$tgl=$_GET['tgl'];
$sql="SELECT sum(pastdue_pokok+pastdue_bunga) as total2 from tbangsuran where nomor_pinjaman = '$no_loan' and status_bayar=1 and tanggal_bayar < '$tgl'";
$sqlProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
$sqlProvider = $sqlProvider->getData();
$sqlData = $sqlProvider[0];

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$sqlData,
    'attributes'=>array(    
        array(
            'label'=>'Total Tunggakan',
            'value'=>$data->total2,
        ),      
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you need a data provider for a detail view, but try this:

```
'attributes'=>array(
    array(
        'label'=>'Total Tunggakan',
        'name'=>'total2',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use data source. It is one item!

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$sqlData,
    'attributes'=>array(    
        array(
            'label'=>'Total Tunggakan',
            'value'=> $sqlData->total2,
        ),      
    ),
));
```